# Cardinality of the set of continuous functions

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

Suppose $(X,\tau)$ and $(Y,\sigma)$ are topological spaces. Let $F(X,Y)$ be the set of continuous functions $X\rightarrow Y$. I want to compute the cardinality of $F(X,Y)$. It depends not only on cardinalities $|X|$ and $|Y|$ but on the topologies as well: just imagine what happens if $X$ or $Y$ is discrete.

**Question: is it possible to write some "topological invariants" $|\tau|$ and $|\sigma|$ that yield the following explicit formula:**
$$|F(X,Y)| = \Theta (|X|,|Y|,|\tau|,|\sigma|)$$

I am sorry for being sloppy: I really need to clarify what a formula is. Ideally, $|\tau|$ would be a collection of cardinals and the formula will be given in the cardinal arithmetic. However, I would be glad to have any other method of computing the cardinality. Thus, "the formula" may be something more general.

Comment: There is a continuum that only allow constant mappings and identity to be continuous. May be relevant

Comment: If you allow proper class invariants, then the answer is yes, because you can essentially encode the whole of F into the invariant in that case.

Comment: You can also trivially do it if you have global choice, from which you get a definable well-ordering of $V$ of order type $Ord$. For any topological space you find the lowest index $\alpha$ of a homeomorphic topological space, and then your 'cardinal invariant' is $\aleph_\alpha$.

Comment: So in particular, the answer is yes in L, where there is a definable such order.

Comment: @James Hanson. What is $V$? What is the lowest index of a homeomorphic topological space?

Comment: @BugsBunny The point is that a lot of information can be coded in cardinals and under certain common set theoretic assumptions you can actually code the homeomorphism type of $(X,\tau)$ by a unique cardinal. So if you're too permissive about what $|\tau|$ and $\Theta$ are, the answer to your question can become very sensitive to set theoretic assumptions and even trivial under certain specific assumptions.

Comment: @Matt $L$ is the constructible universe, mentioned in a comment by Joel. Instead, $V$ is the class of all sets.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, that's what I meant to say, I deleted my comment

Comment: OK, I understand that one can "enumerate" all topologies, say by well-ordering the set of all topologies. I guess I just want to be permissive as soon as the formula remains somewhat constructive...

Comment: Some indications of the difficulty: if $X$ is discrete, or $Y$ is indiscrete, then $F(X,Y)$ has cardinality $|Y|^{|X|}$.

Comment: Next: in <a href="https://eudml.org/doc/170472"> Wann sind alle stetige abbildungen in $Y$ konstant? </a> Herrlich shows that for every $T_1$-spae $Y$ there is a regular space $X$ such that every continuous map from $X$ to $Y$ is constant, so $|F(X,Y)|=|Y|$. There is no bound on the cardinality of $X$. In particular of $Y$ is the space of rationals $F(X,Y)$ is countable for very large $X$.

Comment: One more: every connected space, no matter how large, has exactly two continuous maps to the discrete two-point space.

Comment: Are there known examples, e. g. if the topological spaces are n-dim Riemann Manifolds?

Comment: @KlausLoehnert It seems to me the answer is: if $Y$ is 0-dimensional, it's $c(Y)^{c(X)}$ where $c()$ is the number of connected components; otherwise, $\mathfrak c$.